# Connect to Microsoft Access DB/SharePoint List with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, sharepoint, ado

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database, hosting a SharePoint List, with Powershell. However I can't seem  to find accurate information online demonstrating how to do this. I'm relatively new to SharePoint but am comfortable with Powershell.

The closest demonstration I've found is from the Microsoft Scripting Guys, in the first script on [this page](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/08/13/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script/):

```
$path = "C:dataScriptingGuysHSG_8_10_09HighJumperDatabase.mdb"
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3

$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset

$cn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path")
$rs.Open("SELECT TOP 1 [High Jumper Data].[Name], 
  [High Jumper Data].[Personal Best], [High Jumper Data].[Season Best] 
  FROM [High Jumper Data]
  ORDER BY [High Jumper Data].[Personal Best] 
  DESC , [High Jumper Data].[Season Best] DESC", 
  $cn, $adOpenStatic, $adLockOptimistic)

$rs.MoveFirst()
Write-host "The winner will likely be " $rs.Fields.Item("Name").Value
```

Unfortunately I've never used ADO, and am unsure of what the `Provider` parameter here is referring to.

My objective is to query the SharePoint List for certain information, and then copy that information to another location. Are there comparable PowerShell objects/commands that replicate this script for this purpose?  Or do I need to learn ADO in order to access my SharePoint List on Access?

Answer (score 0):

The part `"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = $path"` is the connection string and consists of two parts, Provider and Data Source

The `Provider` parameter defines the technology, how to get data out of Access. In this case it is MS JET, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-jet

The second part is where your source, the database is located. You need to set the location of your MS Access Database to the variable `$path`  (first line)

e.g. `$path = "D:\folder\myAcessDB.mdb"`

which used in the second part of the Connection String

```
"...DB.4.0;Data Source = **$path**"
```

Another way is using the powershell directly with sharpoint
You could try this Blog post tutorial:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/02/08/better-sharepoint-lists-and-list-items-in-powershell/